# How to use a non-ASCII character, such as a Greek letter, in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, input-encodings

This is the title of the journal article:
Verification of a sliding window protocol in µCRL and PVS.

This is the bibtex file for the same:

```
@article{journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05,
  added-at = {2005-11-15T00:00:00.000+0100},
  author = {Badban, Bahareh and Fokkink, Wan and Groote, Jan Friso and Pang, Jun and van de Pol, Jaco},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2788fbd81863c8e397b18da96324b4860/dblp},
  date = {2005-11-15},
  description = {dblp},
  ee = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00165-005-0070-0},
  interhash = {2d68692f33c41a23a91f6237b2a0e572},
  intrahash = {788fbd81863c8e397b18da96324b4860},
  journal = {Formal Asp. Comput.},
  keywords = {dblp},
  number = 3,
  pages = {342-388},
  timestamp = {2005-11-15T00:00:00.000+0100},
  title = {Verification of a sliding window protocol in µCRL and PVS.},
  url = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/fac/fac17.html#BadbanFGPP05},
  volume = 17,
  year = 2005
}
```

But in PDF, µ symbol is missing.

This is output:

[image]

At dblp, i got the following source:

```
@article{DBLP:journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05,
  author    = {Bahareh Badban and
               Wan Fokkink and
               Jan Friso Groote and
               Jun Pang and
               Jaco van de Pol},
  title     = {Verification of a sliding window protocol in \^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}},
  journal   = {Formal Asp. Comput.},
  volume    = {17},
  number    = {3},
  year      = {2005},
  pages     = {342-388},
  ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00165-005-0070-0},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

This doesn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: The answer depends on how you encode your files; are they UTF-8 or Latin-1 or whatever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to stick to `pdflatex` and encode your files in UTF-8, then the following works:

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05,
  added-at = {2005-11-15T00:00:00.000+0100},
  author = {Badban, Bahareh and Fokkink, Wan and Groote, Jan Friso and Pang, Jun and van de Pol, Jaco},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2788fbd81863c8e397b18da96324b4860/dblp},
  date = {2005-11-15},
  description = {dblp},
  ee = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00165-005-0070-0},
  interhash = {2d68692f33c41a23a91f6237b2a0e572},
  intrahash = {788fbd81863c8e397b18da96324b4860},
  journal = {Formal Asp. Comput.},
  keywords = {dblp},
  number = 3,
  pages = {342-388},
  timestamp = {2005-11-15T00:00:00.000+0100},
  title = {Verification of a sliding window protocol in {µCRL} and {PVS}.},
  url = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/fac/fac17.html#BadbanFGPP05},
  volume = 17,
  year = 2005
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{newunicodechar,textgreek}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newunicodechar{µ}{\textmu}

\begin{document}
\cite{journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The usual `pdflatex file`, `bibtex file`, `pdflatex file`, `pdflatex file` will end up with this.

[image]

I've made some assumptions on what you use for producing the bibliography (here `natbib` and `plainnat` style). The `filecontents*` environment is just to have a self-contained example.

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way is to run your document with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. The code changes in the preamble are simple. Here is an example for `xelatex` with your bib entries:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}
@article{journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05,
  added-at = {2005-11-15T00:00:00.000+0100},
  author = {Badban, Bahareh and Fokkink, Wan and Groote, Jan Friso and Pang, Jun and van de Pol, Jaco},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2788fbd81863c8e397b18da96324b4860/dblp},
  date = {2005-11-15},
  description = {dblp},
  ee = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00165-005-0070-0},
  interhash = {2d68692f33c41a23a91f6237b2a0e572},
  intrahash = {788fbd81863c8e397b18da96324b4860},
  journal = {Formal Asp. Comput.},
  keywords = {dblp},
  number = 3,
  pages = {342-388},
  timestamp = {2005-11-15T00:00:00.000+0100},
  title = {Verification of a sliding window protocol in µCRL and PVS.},
  url = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/fac/fac17.html#BadbanFGPP05},
  volume = 17,
  year = 2005
}
@article{DBLP:journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05,
  author    = {Bahareh Badban and
               Wan Fokkink and
               Jan Friso Groote and
               Jun Pang and
               Jaco van de Pol},
  title     = {Verification of a sliding window protocol in \^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}\^{\i}},
  journal   = {Formal Asp. Comput.},
  volume    = {17},
  number    = {3},
  year      = {2005},
  pages     = {342-388},
  ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00165-005-0070-0},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
foo~\cite{DBLP:journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05,journals/fac/BadbanFGPP05}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

running `xelatex -> bibtex -> xelatex` produces the output:

[image]

Comment: Of course, one should also enclose CRL and PVS in curly braces in order to preserve their capitalization: `{CRL}` and `{PVS}`.

Comment: that depends to the used bibliography style. For my example you are right ...

Comment: I assume xelatex (and lualatex too, for that matter) has no problem with the bib entry is because input is encoded in `utf8`, right?

Comment: @Mico: right, and `bibtex` is not of interest here because the unicode characters are not in the authors names.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
\usepackage{textgreek}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little? Show some code and the corresponding output, for example, even if it completely obvious.